# Loops in Flask with different tags on the formatting

Tags: loops, flask, jinja2

Have a question about doing a loop in Flask over a list. I want the first list item to have different tags than the rest of the list. What I have written below halfway doesn't work properly.

The list I'm iterating over:

```py
[["british cars","Vauxhall","land rover","jaguar"],["German cars","Mercedes","BMW","Audi"]]
```

The HTML/Jinja:

```xml
{% for list in brands %}
    {% for item in list %}
        {% if loop.first %}
            <optgroup label="{{ item }}">
        {% endif %}
            <option value={{ item }}>{{ item }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </optgroup>
{% endfor %}
```

What happens is that the optgroup gets constructed with either "british cars" or "german cars" (as I wanted) but it creates an option with that name also. Something that I don't want.

How Should it be written so the options only shows the various brands?

Comment: @v25 pointed out in their answer that using a list for this has a certain element of fragility: it might be wiser to store in a dictionary or something which is not index-based.

Comment: @monsieuralfonse64 I would agree there may be a better data structure, but felt that was outside the context of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use an `else` clause to prevent the option being added when the loop is on the first iteration.

```html
{% for list in brands %}
    {% for item in list %}
        {% if loop.first %}
            <optgroup label="{{ item }}">
        {% else %}
            <option value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </optgroup>
{% endfor %}
```

Be aware that this assumes all sublists of `brand` are in the same format:

```
['Label','model','model','model']
```

Comment: Would using a dictionary perhaps be a less fragile approach to storing the brands?